# Do I Work with an Orangutan?

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, knowledge

This morning I found myself face-down in front of a large building. It was obvious that I had taken a great fall from one of the rooms above me, but now I apparently had amnesia.
I went in.
I could tell that the building had been built by an American architect, as the ground floor was designated as the first floor, and I guessed that there might be a basement below me.
I started going into random rooms, trying to jog my memory a bit.

1st floor: I poked my head into room 130 and saw someone with a deck of cards. She was staring intently at it, then flipped the top card over with great conviction. She then sighed sadly and scribbled something down on a notepad.

3rd floor: There were a bunch of unsavory mobster-types hanging out by room 364, so I kept going up.

4th floor: I couldn't seem to understand what anyone was talking about, so I continued up.

6th floor: I stopped in room 633 and mellowed out for exactly 7 minutes.

9th (top) floor: I looked into room 910 and was reminded that I had not looked in the basement, so I went back down for a look-see.

Basement: Ahhh! This was finally familiar! I snuggled right into my desk in room 25 and took a nap.

When I woke up I was home, in bed. What a strange dream that had been! Well, no worries, everyone dreams about work sometimes.

> What is my job and where do I work?

Comment: No votes to migrate  to [WorkPlace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Your subject leaves room for only one comment - "Oook"

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You are a:

> Librarian working in a library

and the rooms are:

> [Dewey Decimal Classifications](https://www.oclc.org/en/dewey/features/summaries.html)

1st floor: I poked my head into room 130 and saw someone with a deck of cards. She was staring intently at it, then flipped the top card over with great conviction. She then sighed sadly and scribbled something down on a notepad.

> Dewey Decimal Classification 130: Parapsychology and occultism
>  The woman is attempting to divine the future, and is either attempting to predict the top card of a deck (as a self-test) or is using the deck as a divination tool (see further: Tarot cards)

3rd floor: There were a bunch of unsavory mobster-types hanging out by room 364, so I kept going up.

> Dewey Decimal Classification 364: Criminology
>  This is where books that study the criminal mind go, especially the minds of career criminals or particularly famous criminals.

4th floor: I couldn't seem to understand what anyone was talking about, so I continued up.

> Dewey Decimal Category 400-499: Language
>  Linguistics, phonology, etymology, grammar, etc. They're all here, across a variety of languages, including "Hellenic languages; classical Greek" (480) and "Austronesian and other languages" (499)

6th floor: I stopped in room 633 and mellowed out for exactly 7 minutes.

> Dewey Decimal Classification 633: Field and Plantation Crops
>  7 minutes is exactly [420](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/420_(cannabis_culture)) seconds.

9th (top) floor: I looked into room 910 and was reminded that I had not looked in the basement, so I went back down for a look-see.

> Dewey Decimal Classification 910: Geography and Travel
>  Where did you come from? Where did you go?

Basement: Ahhh! This was finally familiar! I snuggled right into my desk in room 25 and took a nap.

> Dewey Decimal Classification 025: Library operations
>  Get back to work!

Connection to title:

> In Terry Pratchett's Discworld series of novels, the Librarian of the magical Unseen University is an orangutan. (Don't call him a monkey!)

Comment: could you clarify room 633 answer?

Comment: @Untitpoi Clarified the significance of 7 minutes.

Comment: Wow, great riddle and great explanation! +1 to  both!

Comment: I got the answer from the title but had no idea how the rest of it all fitted together. Good job! :)

Comment: The fall was probably caused by using the 'M' word.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is weak but I found it intersesting,
Are you...

> A writer?

It seems like you are dreaming about

> One of your "You are the hero" book, room numbers are in fact page number of the book.
>  You have encounter so many weird things, I think page 910 told you to go to page 25. I would say the basement was the starting point of your adventure.

Answer (score 3):

You are a

> Cleaning lady. Because you have entrance to every floor and every room.

You work in a

> Hotel. You have your rooms in the basement (where they ussually have) and there's also a possibility to take a nap. When you woke up, you were home - as you live there.

Comment: *[Cleaning woman?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w23oPQdnNH8)*

Comment: Could you explain why you believe this is the correct answer? Answers without explanation run the risk of getting deleted.

Comment: Fixed. I hope this will be okay now.

Comment: @Chowzen Can we not be sexist? Cleanliness creation manager please!